# How to deliver our application as a single package

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I did a POC regarding delivering our application as a Docker image, where we were able to install the backend application on our local machine using Docker Desktop and Minikube. 
Now we want to know if we can deliver our application as a single package where the package will contain all the necessary files and scripts to install and configure front end,  backend, and database.
It will also have the scripts to install all the pre-requisites e.g. JAVA, ANGULAR CLI, POSTGRESQL etc.
 
Please give us insights, if this is possible?
If not, then up-to what extent we can go with this approach?
 
Thanks

Any suggestion on this

Comment: Is this as simple as a bash script that you could store in version control somewhere?

Comment: I didn't get your response Sir

Comment: Sir, you are saying I should use Bash

Comment: You haven't really given us a lot of information to go on. I was just suggesting that you write a bash script (assuming you're using linux / mac). What environment are you in? Can you apt install items? Or brew? Or choco (windows)?